# How to write a conditional query formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a query in google sheets:

```
=QUERY('Depot Report'!D:Q, "SELECT I, J WHERE P ='"&AK4&"'")'
```

AK4 is a data validated list of numbers 1-40 which selects all I, J based on the value of AK4.

What I want is "all" in the list that will run the query:

```
=QUERY('Depot Report'!D:Q, "SELECT I, J")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit after your comments

The formula always work very well, but your problem in your sheet is:
Values in column P are not numbers because are formatted as text.
No problem. Solution is very easy.

**SOLUTION**

1. Select all column `P` and format from menu `Automatic`.
2. Also I changed formula a little for cell `S12` for exactly what you need.
   Only copy/paste formula now.

.

```
=QUERY('Depot Report'!D2:Q, "SELECT I, J WHERE 1=1"&IF(T4="All",""," AND P= "&T4&" "))
```

---

Use this formula

```
=QUERY('Depot Report'!D2:Q, "SELECT I, J WHERE 1=1"&IF(AK4="",""," AND P= "&AK4&" "))
```

Comment: Ive tried this but gives me an error and where does =all come in

Comment: It works @SeamusClarke . If you cannot work it, give link from test spreadsheet and I fix it.

Comment: Did you try again? Did you find other solution? Tell me @SeamusClarke

Comment: @swan, i havent been in work yet, ill let u know tomor evening

Comment: So I got the all part to work by putting the following

=QUERY('Depot Report'!D2:Q, "SELECT I, J WHERE 1=1"&IF(AK4="All",""," AND P= "&AK4&" "))

But when I now select the Depot Number (2,3,4 etc) it doesnt bring up anything for me

Comment: @SeamusClarke Of course your solution not work. Give link from test spreadsheet and I fix it.

Comment: Hi Swan, Apologies for not getting back to you sooner, unfortunately my manager wont allow me to post a sample sheet as the data is confidential. 

In layman's terms I have a dropdown list with numbers 1-30 plus the word "all", When I select a number from the drop down list I want to select all records based on that number but when I select all I want it to return all records. I hope that better explains it

TIA

Comment: Don't worry @SeamusClarke . Everybody have managers. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then we can help more. Thank you.

Comment: So I want the formula to go into S12. 
 I want it to show all records by of the depot number in the dropdown box in T4 and if "all" is in T4 show all records

[link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QKELsACIJtuDh3foSE-iwRjXO4l0U4qr2QBqcxeQzqQ/edit?usp=sharing[/link]

Comment: @SeamusClarke You had problem in sheet. Read edit answer. There is easy solution.

Comment: Hi Swen, Your query works for "All but wont bring up anything when I select a depot number. I tried formatting the rows/cells as automatic s you suggested without success